# Using "Plupload" for wordpress frontend form

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So, I have a frontend post form as following:

```
<?php
                        global $current_user;

                        if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] )) {                               
                            if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
                                $title =  $_POST['title'];
                            } else {
                                echo 'Please enter a title';
                            }
                            if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
                                $description = $_POST['description'];
                            } else {
                                echo 'Please enter the content';
                            }
                            $tags = $_POST['post_tags'];                                                            
                            $post = array(
                                'post_title'    => $title,
                                'post_content'  => $description,
                                'post_category' => $_POST['cat'],  
                                'tags_input'    => $tags,                                   
                                'post_status'   => 'publish',           
                                'post_type' => $_POST['post_type']  
                            );                                                          
                            wp_redirect( home_url() );                                      
                        }                           
                        do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
                    ?>
                    <!-- New Post Form -->                  
                    <div class="rh_item_upload">
                        <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">                                                          
                            <input class="input" type="text" id="title" name="title"/>          
                            <textarea class="input" type="text" rows= "3" id="description" name="description" ></textarea>                                  
                            <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple="">                                         
                            <input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="post" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="post" />                              
                            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
                        </form>     
                    </div>
```

Now, it has a basic file (img) upload button.

However, I would like to use Plupload to upload multiple files/client-sie resize/ajax functions to it.

Does anyone know a tutorial or guide that I can follow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form id="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="custom_send_file"/>
    <input class="input" type="text" id="title" name="title"/><br/>
    <textarea class="input" type="text" rows= "3" id="description" name="description" ></textarea><br/>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"  multiple="false" />
    <input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

I think you create your frontend form in a theme.
Then add this in your functions.php
If you don't use a theme, then push this code at the beginning of your page.

```
function custom_send_file()
{
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title'    => $_POST["title"],
        'post_content'  => $_POST["description"],
        'post_status'   => 'publish'
    );
    // this line create a new post with your content form
    $id_post = wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    // upload the file and link it to the post
    media_handle_upload( $key, $id_post );
    // i use this next line to cancel a refresh which send again the form
    wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] );
    exit;
}
if( isset($_POST["action"]) && $_POST["action"] == "custom_send_file" )
    add_action("init", "custom_send_file");
```

I hope that help you.

ps : actually it's only send one file. Maybe just use one input per file (i'll add this tutorial to my website thx for the idea ;) )

Comment: Thank you! I am going to give it a try. Also let me know if you have the tutorial website. I would love to check it out! =)'

Comment: Also I have a question. I see that there is no mention of Plupload function. Is it because Plupload is built into the wordpress?

Comment: I'm not really sure if Wordpress use plupload in that case.
But it works for me.

Me website is a french website. You can find it at http://nozifel.fr/.
The design isn't really great ^^